# How do I dynamically add items to scrollview in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Hello I'm relatively new to kivy. So far doing basic stuff has been relatively straightforward but this has stumped me. I'm making an app that needs to dynamically add rectangular canvas items to a grid in a scrollview. Since I'm doing this I need to create the scrollview in python and not in the .kv file. How can I do this so that the size of the rectangles will be the same as the window size upon resizing the windows?

.py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.graphics import Line,Rectangle
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window

class Scroll(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self,  **kwargs):
        super(Scroll, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
        # Make sure the height is such that there is something to scroll.
        for i in range(100):
            SkillStat = RelativeLayout(pos=(0,0), height=100, size_hint_y=None, size_hint_x=self.width)
            with SkillStat.canvas:
                Rectangle(pos=self.pos,size=(self.width, 90))
            layout.add_widget(SkillStat)

        self.add_widget(layout)
        pass
    pass
class Sheet(Carousel):
    pass

class SheetApp(App):
    def build(self):    
        return Sheet()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SheetApp().run()
```

.kv file:

```
# file name: Sheet.kv

<Sheet>:
    RelativeLayout:
        Scroll:
            size_hint:(1,1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two main problem in your code are:

1. You are doing all your size and position setting of your `SkillStat` and its canvas in an `__init__()` method. In an `__init__()` method of a widget, the position of the widget is always (0,0), and the size is (100, 100). Those properties are not set to real values until the widget is actually drawn.
2. You are doing all this in python instead of in `kv`. In `kv`, bindings are created for many properties that you set, and get automatically updated. If you do your widget setup in python, you must provide those bindings yourself.

Here is a modified version of your `Scroll` class and a new `MyRelativeLayout` class that handle those bindings:

```
class MyRelativeLayout(RelativeLayout):
    def adjust_size(self, *args):
        self.rect.size = self.size  # set the size of the Rectangle


class Scroll(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self,  **kwargs):
        super(Scroll, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
        # Make sure the height is such that there is something to scroll.
        for i in range(100):
            SkillStat = MyRelativeLayout(pos=(0,0), height=100, size_hint=(1.0, None))
            with SkillStat.canvas.before:
                SkillStat.rect = Rectangle()
            SkillStat.bind(size=SkillStat.adjust_size)
            layout.add_widget(SkillStat)
        self.add_widget(layout)
```

Note the `SkillStat.bind()` call to create the needed bindings, and the `Rectangle` is saved as `SkillStat.rect` in each `MyRelativeLayout` instance. Those bindings will get triggered as soon as the `SkillStat` gets displayed, so the initial `pos` and `size` of the `Rectangle` are not needed.

EDIT: Setting the `pos` of the `Rectangle` in a binding was probably causing problems. The default `pos` of the `Rectangle` is `(0,0)`, which is what it should always be. So, we only need to adjust the `size` of the `Rectangle`. I have removed the binding for `pos`.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent suggestion! However it seems like only half the rectangles  get drawn in the scroll and the other half seem to be drawn above. Why is this?

Comment: Odd, I don't see that problem. When I run my posted code, everything that is displayed is in the `Scroll` widget.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your latest comment. See my edited answer above.

Comment: Yes that worked!!!!! Thanks so much!

By the way, where did you learn so much about kivy? I'm looking for some better learning materials as I continue to improve.

Comment: I personally started with the [pong tutorial](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/tutorials/pong.html), then started working on my own projects with lots of reference to this site and to the [kivy documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.html) and occasionally looking at the kivy source code `git clone https://github.com/kivy/kivy`. Spent lots of time trying to understand why MY code wasn't doing what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

1. Create a class with inheritance from RelativeLayout.
2. Update or remove the instructions you have added to a canvas by using `bind` function.

### Snippets

```
class CustomLayout(RelativeLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=(self.width, 90))
        self.bind(pos=self.update_rect, size=self.update_rect)

    def update_rect(self, *args):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
        self.rect.size = self.size
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.graphics import Line, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder


class CustomLayout(RelativeLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=(self.width, 90))
        self.bind(pos=self.update_rect, size=self.update_rect)

    def update_rect(self, *args):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
        self.rect.size = self.size


class Scroll(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Scroll, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
        # Make sure the height is such that there is something to scroll.
        for i in range(100):
            SkillStat = CustomLayout(pos=(0, 0), height=100, size_hint_y=None, size_hint_x=self.width)
            layout.add_widget(SkillStat)

        self.add_widget(layout)


class Sheet(Carousel):
    pass


Builder.load_file('main.kv')


class SheetApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Sheet()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SheetApp().run()
```

### main.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<Sheet>:
    RelativeLayout:
        Scroll:
            size_hint:(1,1)
            bar_width: 10
            effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
            scroll_type: ['bars']
            bar_color: [1, 0, 0, 1]     # red color
            bar_inactive_color: [0, 0, 1, 1]    # blue color
```

## Output

[image: Scrollview - App Start Up]
[image: Scrolling RelativeLaouts]
[image: Window resized - smaller]
[image: Window resized - bigger]